# java writeInt from php,

Tags: java, php, outputstream

hey all i am trying to make a data output stream in php
to write back primitive data types to a java application

i created a class that write the data to an array 
(write it same as java do , copy from java code)

and finally i am writing back the array to the client.

feels like its not working well

for example the writeInt method
send to the java client some wrong values
am i doing ok ?

thank you

here is my code

```
private $buf   = array();


public function writeByte($b) {
  $this->buf[] = pack('c' ,$b);
}

public function writeInt($v) { 
  $this->writeByte($this->shiftRight3($v , 24) & 0xFF);
  $this->writeByte($this->shiftRight3($v , 16) & 0xFF);
  $this->writeByte($this->shiftRight3($v ,  8) & 0xFF);
  $this->writeByte($this->shiftRight3($v ,  0) & 0xFF);

}


private function shiftRight3($a ,$b){
  if(is_numeric($a) && $a < 0){
    return ($a >> $b) + (2<<~$b);
  }else{
    return ($a >> $b);
  }
}


public function toByteArray(){
    return $this->buf;
}
```

this is how i am setting the main php file

```
   header("Content-type: application/octet-stream" ,true);
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" ,true);
```

this is how i am returning the data

```
  $arrResult = $dataOutputStream->toByteArray();
  for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($arrResult) ; $i ++){
     echo $arrResult[$i];
  }
```

I EDIT THE QUESTION ,ACCOURDING TO MY CODE CHANGING
in the java client side seems that i have 2 bytes to read start always
i have 13 , 10 , which is \r \n
how come i am reading them always ?

(in my test i am sending one byte to the java client side ,

```
  URL u = new URL("http://localhost/jtpc/test/inputTest.php");
  URLConnection c = u.openConnection();

  InputStream in =  c.getInputStream();
  int read = 0;
  for (int j = 0; read != -1 ; j++) {
    read = in.read();
    System.out.println("More to read : " + read);
  }
 )

  the output will be ,
   More to read : 13
   More to read : 10
   More to read : 1 (this is the byte i am sending)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing it this way instead of using an intermediary data transport, like JSON, WDDX, or plain old XML?

Comment: yes there is , 
i have a mechanism for a network protocol me and friend implemented  
in java ages ago , and i prefer this protocol on top of other things

Comment: GOT IT WEIRD....
i thing i got my sample working 
i wrote 3 different int values and its look fine
what i had to do is ignore to first 2 bytes that i am reading , 
can some one help me why ?

i update the post on how i am sending byte now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Php has `pack()` function for turning data into binary form. `Unpack()` reverses the operation.

```
$binaryInt = pack('I', $v);
```

Comment: my methods work when i print the values to log before sending them 

just store the data as binary data and send it wont work for me .
i tried to use pack but this wont helping 

echo the data back has strange value in java
 printing them in php side looks ok 
so i guess this is just the binary thing

Comment: @shay - how are you "echoing back" in Java?  I wouldn't expect binary data to be readable if read as bytes and converted / printed as a String.

Comment: @jmz i use pach('c' ,$v) , working great i have another problem now

Comment: *pack working great ,my new problem is why i am always reading \r\n
from the php side

Comment: @Shay: I'm sorry but I don't quite follow what you mean by reading \r\n from the php side? Do you receive a CRLF when you expect something else, or the actual string backslash-r-backslash-n?

Comment: i am always reading backslash-r-backslash-n before the data arrives
so in java side i must 
in.read(); in.read(); , before reading my content

Comment: I quess the PHP side has newlines in some script files. Most common cause is terminating `?>` followed by newlines. These are printed by PHP.

Answer (score 3):

The one thing that strikes me as odd is that you are setting the content type to application/zip, but you don't seem to be creating a ZIP encoded output stream.  Is this an oversight ... or does PHP perform the encoding for you without you asking?

**EDIT**

According to RFC 2046, the recommended content type for a binary data format whose content type is not standardized is ["application/octet-stream"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1).  There is also a practice of defining custom content subtypes with a name starting with "x-" (for experimental), but RFC 2046 says that this practice is now strongly discouraged.

Comment: just trying to force it to some binary data .
there is a generic content type for raw data ?

Comment: i tried this
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

  not helping see my comment to previous post

Comment: @shay - Oh well.  But you needed to fix it anyway.  Otherwise any client (e.g. browser) that that paid attention to content-type headers would attempt to treat the response as ZIP file!

Comment: hey thank you Stephen C , i was able to echo the bytes data back to java , using java DataInputStream to read the data types , but i have to read the two first bytes ,in order to start reading primitive data type , before i am echoing back in php i see that my array length is 4 ,
in java side i need to read first 2 bytes , then read the INT (which is 4 bytes)

Comment: also i update my question for what i am doing 
, the 4 bytes that i am reading is the the source code of DatainputStream.readInt();

Comment: @shay - honestly, I haven't a clue.  I'm not a PHP developer.  All I can say is that you have convinced me that the problem is not on the Java side.  I suggest you pay attention to what the other answers said.

Comment: well after debugin ,more i am always reading 2 unnecessary bytes 
13 , and 10 , they ar \r\n ,
where is this \r\n came from ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that shiftRight3() method, just use >>, as you are masking the result, and then turning it into a chr(). Throw it away.